# ExtJS Grid column with dataIndex from referenced model

Tags: extjs, grid, viewmodel, store, datagridcolumn

I have an ExtJS `gridanel` with a `viewmodel store` bound to it. The model of that store is a defined model with a field that references another model.

For the sake of simplicity here's an example:

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name']
});

Ext.define('Order', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['date', {
        name: 'user',
        reference: 'User'
    }]
});

viewmodel: {
    store: {
        order: {
            model: 'Order',
        }
    }
}
```

In my `gridpanel` I have 2 columns. In one column, `dataIndex: 'date'` works correctly, displaying the date. However, in my second column I want to display the name of the user. I have no idea how to do that. The `user field` itself is on object so declaring `dataIndex: user` doesn't work. I tried `dataIndex: {user.name}` but that doesn't work either. I even tried

```
bind: {
    data: '{user.name}'
}
```

also to no avail. I have found a solution using `renderer` config of the column but it is really ugly and beats the point of having a model reference another if I have to manually traverse the data structure for the appropriate field.

TL;DR
I'm looking for a way to declare a column's `dataIndex` to be a field from a `reference` model.

Comment: I think you'll have to create a flattened structure for your grid to read data from your record.

Comment: I know that but this beats the point of using the "reference" association to show related data from the database. I was hoping to be able to "chain load" the base model with just an `id` which will then call the referenced model's proxy to load the rest of the data.